# Notepad++ Regex Question about Replacing Values

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have no idea regarding regex, so I'm asking here for help

I have the following format in a .txt

```
Code = ZU2J2 | Code Made By = Name1234 | Points = 1337
Code = BAC34 | Code Made By = Name1334 | Points = 1338
Code = KDLS3 | Code Made By = Name3436 | Points = 1122
Code = HSKD3 | Code Made By = Name3434 | Points = 1336
```

And I want to remove/replace everything except the code at the end

It should look like this

```
ZU2J2
BAC34
KDLS3
HSKD3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit Ctrl+H to open the Replace menu. Check the "Regular expression" button.

By using:

Find what: `Code = (\w+) \|.+`

Replace with: `$1`

It will return you

```
ZU2J2
BAC34
KDLS3
HSKD3
```